# Will google cardboard work with my phone?

Tags: google-cardboard

How do i know if google cardboard will work with my phone or not?

I have a gionee p3s. It has magnetic sensor, accelerometer, light sensor and proximity sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use that phone for VR. Its a low resolution phone with 480p by 800p pixels. Also I'm not sure if the 4.5 inch display will cut it. Your better off buying a newer phone like a Samsung, LG, or Motorola with at least 1080p, or else you will get a really sh**ty display. PPI is important for VR.

Edit: sourcing for phone http://www.gsmarena.com/gionee_pioneer_p3s-7805.php

Comment: "*I wouldn't use that phone for VR. Its a low resolution phone with 480p by 800p pixels.*" -- So what? Please clarify. Better to do it with something credible than plainly with opinion.

Comment: It does not have gyro sensor as well.